# How to load preview image in AppWidgetProviderInfo

Tags: android, widget

I googled but can not solve my problem, i think you guys can help me..

So.. I need load the preview image of AppWidgetProviderInfo class.

I see in oficial documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#loadPreviewImage(android.content.Context,%20int)), has a method to load it, but only API level 21+,
and i need this for older version.

Some code here to help..

```
AppWidgetProviderInfo widgetProviderInfo
...
widgetProviderInfo.previewImage; // It's return an int(id from the resource i think).
```

I've tried several ways, but nothing work..

Any ideas how i can load this resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

If anyone needs in the future..

```
AppWidgetProviderInfo widgetProviderInfo
...

String packageName = widgetProviderInfo.provider.getPackageName();

Resources resources = getContext().getPackageManager()
    .getResourcesForApplication(packageName);

Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawableForDensity(
    widgetProviderInfo.previewImage, resources.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
```

Hope that helps someone :)